# basic question on SQL for access

Tags: ms-access

hallo experts,

i have two mdb databaes, say old.mdb and new.mdb, they have the same tables and structures. I just want to verify which records are altered in one specific table in the two database. I googled a long while, and finally came across the following SQL script:

`SELECT Min(tmp.TableName) AS TableName, tmp.ID, tmp.CO1

FROM (
SELECT RECIPETABLE1 IN 'C:\MyRecipes\old.mdb' as TableName, sc_head.ID, sc_head.CO1

FROM sc_head

UNION ALL

SELECT RECIPETABLE1 in 'C:\MyRecipes\new.mdb ' as TableName, compare_sc_head.ID,   compare_sc_head.CO1

FROM compare_sc_head

) AS tmp

GROUP BY tmp.ID, tmp.CO1

HAVING Count(*)=1

ORDER BY tmp.ID`

Bei running, i got an error saying "In-Operator without ()"

Any insights are thankful.

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT Min(tmp.TableName) AS TableName, tmp.ID, tmp.CO1
FROM 
    (SELECT 'RECIPETABLE1'  as TableName, sc_head.ID, sc_head.CO1
     FROM sc_head IN 'C:\MyRecipes\old.mdb'
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 'RECIPETABLE2'  as TableName, compare_sc_head.ID, compare_sc_head.CO1
     FROM compare_sc_head in 'C:\MyRecipes\new.mdb') As tmp
GROUP BY tmp.ID, tmp.CO1
HAVING Count(*)=1
ORDER BY tmp.ID
```

However, I suggest it would be easier to use a little VBA for the comparison.

It is not too unpleasant comparing a single table with a very small number of fields using the query design window, however, for more tables of fields, it is far easier to use VBA.

Here are some queries that will run in the query design window.

Record in NewDB but not in OldDB

```
SELECT n.ID, n.CO1
FROM 
   (SELECT ID, CO1
    FROM compare_sc_head 
    IN 'C:\MyRecipes\new.mdb') AS n 
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT ID, CO1
    FROM sc_head 
    IN 'C:\MyRecipes\old.mdb') AS o 
ON n.ID = o.ID
WHERE o.ID Is Null
```

Record in OldDB but not in NewDB

```
SELECT o.ID, o.CO1
FROM 
   (SELECT ID, CO1
    FROM sc_head 
    IN 'C:\MyRecipes\old.mdb') AS o 
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT ID, CO1
    FROM compare_sc_head 
    IN 'C:\MyRecipes\new.mdb') AS n 
ON o.ID = n.ID
WHERE n.ID Is Null
```

Record ID matches but CO1 does not

```
SELECT n.ID, n.CO1, o.CO1
FROM 
   (SELECT ID, CO1
    FROM sc_head 
    IN 'C:\MyRecipes\old.mdb') AS o 
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT ID, CO1
    FROM compare_sc_head 
    IN 'C:\MyRecipes\new.mdb') AS n 
ON o.ID = n.ID
WHERE n.CO1 & "" <> o.CO1 & ""
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction. By running I have another error: Syntax error in Union Query.

Comment: great! It works this time. By running this script I get all the fields displayed instead of only the fields which are changed. Is there any other method?

Comment: @JohnMunich For changes, you really need to check for new records, deleted records and unmatched records. This needs either about three queries or some VBA. Which do you prefer?

Comment: @Remou Since i have spent a lot of time on SQL scripts, i prefer adding more queries. It would be thankful, if you could give me advice on this issue.

Comment: There is a lot to be said for trying out ideas yourself :)